Does $f_n\sim g_n$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n$ for uniformly convergent sequences of PDFs hold over these vector operations?
Let $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the set of infinite sequences of functions $f_n: \mathbb{Z} \to (0,1)$ satisfying
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(k) = 1,$$
such that any such sequence, $f_n$, converges uniformly to a function $f$. For any $f_n, g_n \in S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, define addition and scalar multiplication as follows.
$$(f_n+g_n)(k) = \frac{f_n(k)g_n(k)}{\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n(m)g_n(m)}$$
$$(cf_n)(k) = \frac{f_n(k)^c}{\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n(m)^c}$$
Let $S_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the set of infinite sequences of continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ that are differentiable "almost everywhere" (at all points except a set of Lebesgue measure zero) satisfying
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x){\rm d}x = 1,$$
such that any such sequence, $f_n$, converges uniformly to a function $f$. For any $f_n, g_n \in S_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, define addition and scalar multiplication as follows.
$$(f_n+g_n)(x) = \frac{f_n(x)g_n(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(t)g_n(t){\rm d}t}$$
$$(cf_n)(x) = \frac{f_n(x)^c}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(t)^c{\rm d}t}$$
Define an equivalence relation on $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $S_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that, for any $f_n$ and $g_n$ in each set, $f_n\sim g_n$ if and only if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n.$$
What I would like to figure out is, given $c \in\mathbb{R}$ and $a_n, b_n, \alpha_n, \beta_n$ in either set such that $a_n\sim \alpha_n$ and $b_n\sim \beta_n$, does it follow that $a_n+b_n \sim \alpha_n+\beta_n$ and $ca_n \sim c\alpha_n$?
Additionally, I'd like to determine if this equivalence holds over a type of inner product. Specifically, given $a_n, b_n, \alpha_n, \beta_n \in S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $a_n\sim \alpha_n$ and $b_n\sim \beta_n$, does it follow that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k \in\mathbb{Z}} \ln\left(\frac{a_n(k+1)}{a_n(k)}\right)\ln\left(\frac{b_n(k+1)}{b_n(k)}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k \in\mathbb{Z}} \ln\left(\frac{\alpha_n(k+1)}{\alpha_n(k)}\right)\ln\left(\frac{\beta_n(k+1)}{\beta_n(k)}\right)\textbf{,}$$
and given $a_n, b_n, \alpha_n, \beta_n \in S_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $a_n\sim \alpha_n$ and $b_n\sim \beta_n$ does it follow that,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a_n'(x)b_n'(x)}{a_n(x)b_n(x)}{\rm d}x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\alpha_n'(x)\beta_n'(x)}{\alpha_n(x)\beta_n(x)}{\rm d}x\textbf{?}$$
The motivation for this is that I'd like to define two inner product spaces $V_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ as the sets of equivalence classes of $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $S_{\mathbb{R}}$ with the definitions of addition, scalar multiplication, and the inner product as given above.
Do the equivalence relations hold over these operations as stated? If so, how would I go about proving it? If not, why not, and is there some obvious alteration/restriction that can be made to $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and/or $S_{\mathbb{R}}$ so that they do hold? I now suspect that a restriction to uniformly convergent sequences is the key, but how could that restriction allow us to prove these relations?
